# Fraction of electrons that diffuse across pn junction?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

Roughly how large fraction of the surplus electrons from the n-type doping will transfer across to the p-type material? Interested in just a rough estimate, is it closer to 1%, 50%, 100%?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The silicon in a pn-junction diode is doped with 1 ppm n-type atoms, often phosphorous, and 1 parts per thousand p-type, group 3 like boron. Electrons will transfer from the n-type material over the p-n junction to form a "depletion region". I am interested in if only a very very small fraction will transfer (requiring a lot of n-type atoms for each charge transferred), or if actually quite a lot of it transfers. This is an easy to understand question. It is not hard to tell what it asks.

Comment: Boron doping is also at the ppm level. $10^{19}$ is way too high a doping level for any device.

Comment: Maybe you are right, I am no expert on it. I got the numbers from solar cells, here https://www.researchgate.net/post/What-is-the-Best-ratio-of-Boron-doped-or-Phosphorus-doped-silicon-SiB. But I am not an expert on that, and I myself just want a rough idea about what those fractions are. I could Google around on it more, but that it was somewhere around ppm was good enough detail for me. And here I am asking about the fraction of electrons from n-type atoms that will transfer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, 100% of the surplus electrons and holes in the depletion region diffuse away. That's why we call it depleted: there are no free carriers except for a tiny number thermally excited from the surrounding undepleted material.

Answer (score 0):

A real P-N junction is not a slab of P next to a slab of N material, it is a diffused alloy, with a dopant gradient.   It is  possible to calculate charge-carrier concentration in the junction, but as for dopant atoms, one typically assumes those are ionized completely; 100% of the charge
carriers from dopant atoms are presumed to be mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the surplus electrons, $100\%$ will be diffused if the circuit is closed and potential is grater than *Knee voltage*. Without this, due to barrier potential, it will be eventually stopped from being fully diffused.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).